# iBooks alignment examples fail as 'Invalid Equation'

Tags: latex, ibook-author

Copy/pasting all three of the alignment examples from Apple's [iBooks Author : About LaTex](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5321) fail with 'Invalid Equation'. For example

[image]

What is the correct format for alignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace `ALIGNED.EN_US` with `aligned`, and replace `RED.EN_US` with `red`. Good luck!